# HIVE splitting string

Tags: hadoop, split, hive

HIVE :-
I have a column changeContext==>"A345|Fq*A|2017-05-01|2017-05-01" (string) out of which I need to extract A345 as another column. Any suggestion ? P.S. I have tried regexp_extract (running into vertex failure) so any other solution would be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with t as (select "A345|Fq*A|2017-05-01|2017-05-01" as changeContext)

select  substring_index(changeContext,'|',1)                    option_1
       ,split(changeContext,'\\|')[0]                           option_2
       ,substr(changeContext,1,instr(changeContext,'|')-1)      option_3
       ,regexp_extract(changeContext,'[^|]*',0)                 option_4
       ,regexp_replace(changeContext,'\\|.*','')                option_5

from    t
```

---

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| option_1 | option_2 | option_3 | option_4 | option_5 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| A345     | A345     | A345     | A345     | A345     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: sorry if I distrub, would u mind to parse it for me?  ,SUBSTR(COLUMNSSS, INSTR((CCVALUE),'^',1,10)  +1, INSTR((CCVALUE),'^',1,11)-1 - INSTR((CCVALUE),'^',1,10)) CZZ

Comment: already tried split (ccvalue,'\\^)[10] but not works